# Celery Best Practices - Multiple Celery Instances with multiple Django Projects

Tags: python, django, rabbitmq, celery

I have spent a couple days trying to get this to work - Haven't found a way.
Following is what I'm trying to do.

1. I have 2 related but independant django projects, each of whom use celery
2. Each project has some celery interactions (Qs, results etc) locally, ie, within the project - Celery/RabbitMQ Routing for this part is well documented and I don't think i'll have issues fine-tuning this

**3**. I also have a set of interactions using **rabbitmq API's between the 2 projects**. Lets say I want to send a hello message from one django instance (server A) to the other one (server B)

I've tried all sorts of experiments - **It fails each time.**

- From the **dreaded vhost permission error**:

  ChannelClosed: (406, "PRECONDITION_FAILED - parameters for queue 'wizcard' in vhost '/' not equivalent")
  _
  (this happens in the channel.declare('shared_q_between_A_and_B) routine)
- to messages not going to the desired Qs, I have just not been able to make it work
- to "[2014-12-08 13:08:08,521: ERROR/MainProcess] Received unregistered task of type on.." which I see on the Server A celery logs upon starting the Server B celery instance

Can someone please tell me how to go about setting this up and what the best practices are.

Comment: You may want to check out federation https://www.rabbitmq.com/federation.html

Comment: Well, I thought what I'm trying should be fairly common...when using rabbitmq directly, I'm able to send a "hello" between a producer and consumer...was hoping it would extend the same when celery got into the picture.

Comment: I'm sorry I may have miss read what you were trying to accomplish.  Are you trying to start up multiple celery workers working on different projects?  Little confused on the multiple django instances I guess

Comment: Yes. 2 separate django projects each using celery (hence 2 separate celery instances). I would like to be able to send amqp messages between the 2 django projects.

Comment: So i was able to get beyond this, and hit the next roadblock - http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/extending.html#custom-message-consumers seems to be the answer I'm looking for...trying to get it to work. If anyone has seen it working, it would great to hear and compare notes

Comment: Hay did you find the solution for this problem? Please provide any useful links if available.